# How can we solve the following system of equations using Gauss-Seidel iteration?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
 4 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
 3 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & 2 & -1 \\
 \end{bmatrix} \mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}-10 \\ 8 \\ 7 \\ -5 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Gauss-Seidel method diverges for this system in the current form.

As there is no apparent way to change the coefficient matrix into a diagonally dominant matrix by row exchanges, I tried to make the situation better by putting 2nd row in 1st place, 4th row in 2nd place, 1st row to 4th place, keeping 3rd in 3rd place.

This also did not help.

Any ideas how to proceed in this case and in general how to tackle problems of this kind?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner There is nothing on the page related to what I am asking here. It lists two criteria for convergence: (1) matrix is positive-definite (2) it is diagonally dominant. All the examples taken are of diagonally dominant matrices.

Comment: @Moo I already saw it. It's just an example of a matrix which cannot be put into diagonally dominant form. The ppt doesn't provide any solution to that.

Comment: @Moo "As there is no apparent way to change the coefficient matrix into a diagonally dominant matrix by row exchanges.." - this is what I have written in the question itself.

Comment: Actually this is a past year question asked in a competitive exam. Is that enough reason to try and solve it?

Comment: What are the available "tools" to solve this problem? A computer can be handy. Out of 24 possible row permutations, only 2 lead to a convergent forward Gauss-Seidel, 3 give a convergent backward method. For example, a convergent backward method can be obtained by swapping the row permutation $(2,3,4,1)$, that is, by the upwards circular shift of the rows.